# Idea + Scala-Play: Editor compiler cannot resolve Twirl templates e.g. views.html.index

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

For some reason IntelliJ Idea version 2016.2.5 editor compiler is not able to recognize or find the compiled twirl templates e.g.

```
def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index()) // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< cannot resolve symbol index
}
```

Is there a setting that can fix this?

**UPDATE** I installed Idea Community 2017.1 and also have the issue. I use it with its corresponding SBT and Scala plugins.

Comment: Did you check the [list of open issues](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL?q=twirl%20%23unresolved) before submitting this question?

Comment: Can you also post your folder and package structure, the file names of the Twirl files, and the package name listed in the compiled Twirl files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a proper build tool that compiles the Twirl files. I've used IntelliJ with Gradle and the Play framework before without any issues.

https://github.com/67726e/gradle-twirl

But the authors of the framework also show an example with SBT:

https://github.com/playframework/twirl

Comment: I use SBT importing its corresponding Play-SBT plugin that is able to of course compile all well and nice. But somehow from the IntelliJ IDE doesn't work.